# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta para varias tablas? Haciendo promedios

Tags: mysql

Tengo una base de datos, básicamente la BD es de una aplicación de calificación de personas por competencias, hay dos usuarios el evaluador y el evaluado.

Voy a mostrar las tablas y como esta compuesta que creo que se deben de utilizar para esta consulta:

funcionario: En esta tabala se muestran las personas, en esta misma tabla se encuentra el evaluador y el evaluado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

evaluadores: En esta tabla se relaciona el id del evaluador(idCargo) con el id del evaluado(idCargoEvaluado)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

resultado: En esta tabla se muestra los resultados obtenidos (valor)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

competencia: En esta tabla esta el nombre de la competencia por el cual cada persona fue evaluada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

nucleo: En esta tabla esta los nucleos de la competencia, osea que cada competencia tiene uno o más nucleos, los nucleos tienen valores definidos y para sacar el total(de la competencia) se hace un promedio pero para sacarlo toca por consulta(que no sé como realizarla).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cargoCompetencia: En esta tabla esta un valor "esperado", es un valor que se espera que saque la persona por competencia, el cual debe ser comparado en la consulta y mostrar si es inferior, igual o superior

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

objetivos: En esta tabla estan unas observaciones del evaluador el cual también se debe mostrar en la consulta, son 4 campos que se utilizan(resaltados en amarillo).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo unas consultas que he hecho pues la verdad soy muy novato en eso y por ello estoy aquí

La primera consulta que tengo es la selección de los evaluadores con los evaluados

`select distinct fun.documento, fun.nombre as Nombre_Evaluador, (select documento from funcionario where id= resul.idFuncionario) as documento, (select nombre from funcionario where id= resul.idFuncionario) as Nombre_Evaluado 
from funcionario fun, resultados resul, competencia comp, nucleo nuc where resul.idEvaluador = fun.id ORDER by Nombre_Evaluador`

En la segunda consulta que tengo es esta:

`select distinct  fun.documento, fun.nombre as Nombre_Evaluador, (select documento from funcionario where id= resul.idFuncionario) as documento,
(select nombre from funcionario where id= resul.idFuncionario) as Nombre_Evaluado, resul.valor,  comp.nombre as nombre_competencia
from funcionario fun, resultados resul, competencia comp, nucleo nuc where resul.idEvaluador = fun.id and resul.nucleo = nuc.id and nuc.idCompetencia = comp.id`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y desde esta consulta se complican las cosas para mi pues tengo que sacar el promedio de las competencias (la competencia que se repite)

El objetivo de pedir ayuda por este medio es: Realizar el promedio de las competencias que se repitan(el cual no tengo ni idea de como se hace en mysql), la razón de que se repitan es que cada competencia tiene sus nucleos tiene uno o más de ellos, además que cada nucleo tiene un puntaje y el puntaje de este depende del cargo de la persona, los puntajes se deben comparar con el campo "esperado" de la tabla "cargoCompetencia" y deben decir si es inferior esperado o superior, y por ultimo agregar a cada evaluado las observaciones que le hizo el evaluado que son los tres últimos campos de la tabla "objetivos".

He intentado estudiar mysql para solucionar esto tan complejo (al menos para mi), pero no he llegado a nada desde hace más de una semana. y como ven mis consultas son algo sencillas, además que me ayudarian para otros proyectos, agradezco aquella persona que me quiera ayudar, quedo muy atento por si hay dudas(espero que haya quedado bien explicado).

Mil Gracias,

Answer (score 0):

## Calcular promedio en MySQL

El promedio se puede calcular directamente de MySQL con la funcion AVG().

Para obtener los promedios de cada usuario diferente, algo así te serviría.

```
SELECT id_alumno, AVG(valor_nota)
FROM tabla
GROUP BY id_alumno;
```

Donde GROUP BY hace prácticamente todo el trabajo de agrupación por registro distinto.

#### Adaptándolo al entorno

Tu SQL es esto:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fun.documento, 
                fun.nombre AS Nombre_Evaluador, 
                (SELECT documento 
                 FROM   funcionario 
                 WHERE  id = resul.idfuncionario) AS documento, 
                (SELECT nombre 
                 FROM   funcionario 
                 WHERE  id = resul.idfuncionario) AS Nombre_Evaluado, 
                resul.valor, 
                comp.nombre AS nombre_competencia 
FROM   funcionario fun, 
       resultados resul, 
       competencia comp, 
       nucleo nuc 
WHERE  resul.idevaluador = fun.id 
       AND resul.nucleo = nuc.id 
       AND nuc.idcompetencia = comp.id
```

Ya adaptado al entorno, seria algo asi:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fun.documento, 
                fun.nombre AS Nombre_Evaluador, 
                (SELECT documento 
                 FROM   funcionario 
                 WHERE  id = resul.idfuncionario) AS documento, 
                (SELECT nombre 
                 FROM   funcionario 
                 WHERE  id = resul.idfuncionario) AS Nombre_Evaluado, 
                AVG(valor), 
                comp.nombre AS nombre_competencia 
FROM   funcionario fun, 
       resultados resul, 
       competencia comp, 
       nucleo nuc 
WHERE  resul.idevaluador = fun.id 
       AND resul.nucleo = nuc.id 
       AND nuc.idcompetencia = comp.id 
GROUP BY competencia;
```

Comment: Hola ya he utilizado el group by y no funciona, pues solamente se agrupan la catidad que hay de competencias serviria con agrupando con cada evaluado